# Ristrict UITableViewCell to move in particular section

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
   if (indexPath.section == 1) {
        return NO;
   }
   else {
        return YES;
   }
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
     if (indexPath.section == 1) {
            return NO;
     }
     else {
            return YES;
     }
}
```

I have 2 sections in my tableView. I want my tableViewcells to be moved only in first section(not for second). Currently if i drag my tableCell to second section, It has a crash.

Comment: try to implement this only cause crash (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

Comment: set this method also in your class...- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}

Comment: I think you have a mistake, You want section 1 to be editable but not section 2 ? You are telling the app that the sections are editable if they are not section 1 ?

 For those two methods simply do: return indexPath.section == 1;

Comment: sorry for my bad language )) i have 2 sections - zero and one. in zero sections i can move my row, but in one sections can not move section, and i can not move row from zero sections in one sections. But now i can move row between sections, i need lock it

Comment: As for the crash, is there a crash message ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for this method -

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toProposedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)proposedDestinationIndexPath
{
   if (proposedDestinationIndexPath.section != 0)
   {
       return sourceIndexPath;
   }

   return proposedDestinationIndexPath;
 }
```

It will restrict you to move your rows in section 0 only. If you try to move row from section 0 to 1, it'll return the previous indexpath of the cell